# Early access for JRE 7

Tags: java

Is there a way in which I can get early access to the JRE 7 update builds?

The oracle early access [site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html) or the jdk7 [site](https://jdk7.java.net/) do not provide any builds to download.

Comment: Early access to the updates?

Comment: Java 7 is release. Whhy early access to a final product?

Comment: may be you meant JRE 8?

Comment: Java 7 was released 2011.

Answer (score 3):

Java is developed at [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/). The [Mercurial repository for updates to Java 7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u) is open for everybody.

Comment: Lutz,  Thanks for the info. Do we have to download and build it locally or is there a way we can get the builds directly?